# CMake add_custom_target() with shell looping construct

Tags: cmake

I asked this in the LLVM beginner's forum too, unfortunately didn't get any response after a day, hence posting it here for pointers. So, Let’s say I have a file that gets created during the build time and then I want to process that file somehow, In this example, I would like to read the file line by line and hence I try to do the following:

```
add_custom_target(mytarget
    COMMAND while read -r line ; do echo "$line" ; done < ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/temp.txt
    VERBATIM
)
```

however I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "do")
```

Please suggest how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `;` is treated as separator by cmake, i.e. the following 2 lines have the same effect

```
set(VAR foo bar)
set(VAR foo;bar)
```

It's better to try to avoid platform dependent logic like this anyways.

In this case you could simply use cmake's `cat` command line tool

```
add_custom_target(mytarget
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E cat ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/temp.txt
    VERBATIM
)
```

or use a cmake script file

**script.cmake**

```
file(READ "${INPUT}" FILE_CONTENTS)
message(STATUS "${FILE_CONTENTS}")
```

```
add_custom_target(mytarget
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D "INPUT=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/temp.txt" -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script.cmake
    VERBATIM
)
```

If you really need to use the exact command in the question, you could also create a script file to run instead.

Comment: Sorry, I was on vacation, hence I couldn't check this earlier. Thank you for your help. What you have suggested works (small correction needed with the cmake FILE command, i.e. file(READ "${INPUT}" FILE_CONTENTS) 

However, instead of just reading a file line by line (as I mentioned in the above example, and was meant only as an example) if there are lot more operations needed, then perhaps it is much better to invoke the other scripting language such as bash or python, which i think should be possible as well.